# Recyclerview: how do I keep original Adapter position from original list in a filtered list?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list of CardView items and an onClickListener() in the Adapter file that is used in the MainActivity via onItemClick() to launch a CardViewDetails Activity.  All works fine.  I then added a Spinner to filter the CardViews based on one criteria.  The filtering works as expected.  However, now when I click on a CardView in the filtered list, the wrong CardView is shown to the user in the CardViewDetails Activity.

For example, say I have 15 CardView items in the RecyclerView list.  And assume I make a selection in the Spinner dropdown that filters the list to three CardViews.  Assume I now click on the second CardView in the filtered list AND  that CardView item was the **last** CardView in the original RecyclerView list.  The UI goes to the CardViewDetails Activity as expected, but returns the second CardView from the **original list** rather than the last CardView from the original list that I was expecting.

How do I keep the original Adapter position in the ViewHolder returned with the original RecyclerView list when the adapter updates after the list is filtered with the Spinner selection?  Should I be making a copy of the original list and somehow using the copied list in the Adapter file?

```
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ListItem> listItems;
    public Context context;
    private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

    public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener) {
        this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;
    }

    // Do R. list filtering from MainActivity.
    public ArrayList<ListItem> filter2(List<ListItem> listItems, String filterType) {

        final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListItem item : listItems) {
            final String cardTypeTest = item.getType();

            if (cardTypeTest.equals(filterType)) {
                filteredModelList2.add(item);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList2;
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.addAll(listItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent,false);
        final ItemHolder itemHolder = new ItemHolder(view);

        // Attach a Click listener to the items's (row) view.
        // onItemClick is the click method in MainActivity.
        itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Handles the row being clicked.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int adapterPos = itemHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // get the item position.
                if (adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                        recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemHolder.itemView,adapterPos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    return itemHolder;
    }

RecyclerItemClickListener.java

public interface RecyclerItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

}

MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    RecyclerItemClickListener {

    private MyRecylerAdapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem> allList = null; 
    private Spinner spinner2;    
    private ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList0 = null;

    ...
    // Set up a spinner instance and apply an OnItemSelectedListener on it.
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.skycard_filter);
    final String[] spinnerItems2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skycard_filters);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout        
    final CustomAdapter<String> adapter2 = new CustomAdapter<>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerItems2);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            final String type = "CardView Type";
            filteredModelList0 = adapter.filter2(adapter.listItems,type);
            ...

            switch (position) {                        
                    case 0:
                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.addAll(allList);
                        // Need to filter the entire R. list
                        filteredModelList0 = adapter.filter2(adapter.listItems, type);
                        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList0);
                    break;
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view,int position) {        

        // Create a new intent to send data from this MainActivity to the CardViewDetails Activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,CardViewDetails.class);
        // Send the position of the CardView item that was clicked on through 
        // the intent.
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: You could try to send the CardView's ID instead of its position in your intent.

Comment: Ok, I save the ID in an SQLite database, so replace the position with getId() from the Model (ListItem) class ?

Comment: That may not work because the ID might have changed if the list was filtered so the wrong ID could be sent in the intent.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey How to solve this query. I have the same issue.

Comment: @A.R. The spinner was too problematic for me.  I replaced with an AlertDialog.